# "В неделю", корректное употребление

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, грамматика

Можно ли употреблять выражение, такое как "В неделю я должен читать по две книги", или же это предложение является грамматически неправильным?

Comment: Остальное в вашем тексте - лишнее.

Comment: Эх, повеселили, повеселили, шутник!)))

Answer (score 1):

Лучше бы, конечно, без изощрённого "пиетета", попроще, а то звучит как-то иронически, не про нас, а уж к империи мы точно отношения не имеем. Как-то отвечать не хочется.

Грамматически всё верно. По две книги в неделю - вполне нормально звучит. Это же не высокий стиль. А что Вас насторожило? Инверсия: "в неделю" на первом месте? Это возможно. Или "по"? Лучше бы "две книги в неделю" или "по две книги каждую неделю". Но и Ваш вариант возможен.

Comment: Простите, если Вас это оскорбило, поверьте, у меня не было злого умысла. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Я не Людмила, но поверить трудно...